# Creating Lite mixed entities with breeze

Tags: breeze, single-page-application

We are working on an SPA which uses Durandal + Breeze, we have used DTOs for data transfer, is there a way in Breeze through which we can make some of the properties of objects as Observable while keeping the rest as plain Javascript properties.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, but depending on your willingness to look at the breeze source, you could take a look at the JsonResultsAdapter and the "ko" (knockout) model library implementation. Together these two control how entities and projections get materialized.